# how to calculate the integration of exponential with polynomial expression?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am working on an integration, where after applying $e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$, I have the following transform:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty \log(1+x)e^{-\frac{(b+1)x}{a}}\sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{(\frac{x}{2})^{2m}}{m!(m+1)}dx &= \int_0^\infty \log(1+x)e^{-\frac{(b+1)x}{a}}\sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{(\frac{x^2}{4})^{m}}{m!}\frac{1}{m+1}dx \\
& = \int_0^\infty \log(1+x)e^{-\frac{(b+1)x}{a}} \frac{4(e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}-1)}{x^2}dx\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I found myself helplessness with this integration while trying with integration by parts method.

Would anyone please guide me on this integral?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!
I am also worrying about this...

Comment: Oops, I need the final expression after the integration.

Comment: Thank you so much, Yuriy. Let me check this error.

Comment: Dear Yuriy, would you please guide me on the derivation 



$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{x}{2})^{2m}}{m!(m+1)} = \frac{4(e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}-1)}{x^2}$




I am still cannot follow this... Thank you so much!

Comment: $$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{y^m}{m!(m+1)}= \frac{1}{y} \sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{y^{m+1}}{m!(m+1)}=$$ $$=\frac{1}{y} \sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{y^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}=\frac{1}{y} \sum_{m = 1}^\infty\frac{y^m}{m!}=$$ $$=\frac{1}{y} \left(e^y-1 \right)$$ Now substitute $y=x^2/4$

Comment: But it doesn't matter because this still leads to a divergent integral. You should check the reasoning which led you to the very first formula in your post, because apparently there's something wrong in the earlier steps

Comment: @Yuriy, Many many thanks for your patient! I really appreciate it a lot! Let me try whether I can get some approximate expression within a given interval or not from here. All the Best Wishes and have a good night!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral really depends on a single parameter $c=\frac{b+1}{a}$ as can be seen:

$$
\int_0^\infty \log(1+x)e^{\frac{ax^2 - 4(b+1)x}{4a}}dx=\int_0^\infty \log(1+x)e^{x^2/4 - c x}dx
$$

However, no matter which value $c$ takes, the integral **diverges** because of the $e^{x^2}$ term which goes to infinity as $x \to \infty$. (And $x^2$ grows faster than $cx$ for any $c$).

$$
\int_0^\infty \log(1+x)e^{\frac{ax^2 - 4(b+1)x}{4a}}dx=\infty
$$

---

Update:

In answer to the questions about the sum in the edited post:

$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{y^m}{m!(m+1)}= \frac{1}{y} \sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{y^{m+1}}{m!(m+1)}=$$ $$=\frac{1}{y} \sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{y^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}=\frac{1}{y} \sum_{m = 1}^\infty\frac{y^m}{m!}=$$ $$=\frac{1}{y} \left(e^y-1 \right)$$ Now substitute $y=x^2/4$.

---

As this expression still leads to a diverging integral (now with additional problem at $x=0$), there must me some error in the prior reasoning which led to the sum in the first place.

Comment: I further added my prior calculations.
Is there anything wrong with my calculations?
This integration comes from calculating the achievable sum rate of the wireless systems with Rician channel. 
Typically, it should have an expression but not approach infinity...

Comment: @zhd, first yes, you've made a mistake, because your sum should be equal to $4(e^{x^2/4}-1)/x^2$ because of the $1/(m+1)$ term. Second, fixing your mistake still doesn't make the integral converge. The problem is the sign in front of $x^2$ inside the exponential. Though now $1/x^2$ terms is also a problem around $0$

Comment: Thank yo so much for your patient reply. I want cry now...

Comment: @zhd, there's no need to do that. You could check your prior derivation of the sum involved (maybe there's some error there) or better yet, google this topic since there's a chance someone already solved this problem. Again, not the integral, but how you obtain it

Comment: Okay, let me try, thank you so much for your patient reply and encouragement! Let me check it carefully.